# Detect a given day between two days of the week

Tags: c#, datetime, weekday

I would like to detect if a given day is between two days of the week using C#. So the scenario would be that detecting Tuesday (Could be `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`) is between Monday to Saturday. Likewise, I need to detect a given day is between two certain days of the week and treat it differently. The two certain days are static and the given date must be dynamic
as it depends on what day the users access the system.

Comment: Can the two days wrap around the end of the week? I.e. can you have Friday–Monday?

Comment: Yeah.. if there's no differences in logic, I'm happy to accept Monday - Friday as an example scenario.In my problem domain I have two scenarios to fill. Monday - Saturday , and Just Sunday itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool IsBetween(DayOfWeek min, DayOfWeek max, DayOfWeek toCheck)
{   
    if (min <= max)
        return toCheck >= min && toCheck <= max;

    return toCheck >= min || toCheck <= max;
}
```

Comment: Can I use the same logic above to detect the time of access also? such as detecting 10am(time of access - dynamic) is between 6am and 10pm?

Answer (score 3):

```
var currentDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
bool isBetween = DayOfWeek.Monday < currentDay
    && currentDay < DayOfWeek.Saturday;
```

Comment: This check is exclusive, so it returns true for Tuesday–Friday.